# Как правильно реализовать функцию воспроизведения звука при открытии нового сообщения?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как правильно реализовать функцию воспроизведения звука при открытии нового сообщения?

из кода найденного на просторах интернета извлек:

```
$(function() {
    chatAudio = function() {
    $('<audio id="chatAudio"><source src="sound.ogg" type="audio/ogg"><source src="sound.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"><source src="sound.aac" type="audio/aac"></audio>').appendTo('body');
    }
});
```

Буду признателен за любую помощь!

Answer (score 1):

```
var audio=new Audio('sound.mp3');
audio.play();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function () {
    var appendChatAudio = function() {
        $('<audio id="chatAudio"><source src="test.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>').appendTo('body');

        $("#chatAudio").on("canplay", function () {
            // Здесь ваше аудио готово к воспроизведению
            // Можем подписаться на какой-либо ивент для его воспрозиведения
            // В вашем случае это может быть открытие нового сообщения
            $("#play-audio").click(function () {
                // Получаем элемент, и вызываем у него метод play()
                $("#chatAudio").get(0).play();
            });
        });
    };

    appendChatAudio();
});
```